# Global, dynamic checkboxes android

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

I have a ReserveNodesFragment where i create dynamically checkBoxes.
I have declared the orbitCheckBoxes globally, since another fragment should access them, too.

I have declared the checkBoxes globally in the GlobalData.java:

```
public class GlobalData extends Application{

       ...

       ...

        public ArrayList<CheckBox> orbitCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

        //Accessor and methods for orbit checkboxes
        public  ArrayList<CheckBox> getOrbitCheckBoxes() {
             return this.orbitCheckBoxes;
        }

        public  void setOrbitCheckBoxes(CheckBox checkbox) {
             this.orbitCheckBoxes.add(checkbox);
        }

        public void setOrbitCheckBoxesText(int i, String text){
             this.orbitCheckBoxes.get(i).setText(text);
        }

       public void clearOrbitCheckBoxes(){
             this.orbitCheckBoxes.clear();
       }
```

}

The fragment that creates the CheckBoxes dynamically is the following:

```
    public class ReserveNodesFragment extends Fragment {

         GlobalData appState;

         LinearLayout reserveNodesView;          

         @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    reserveNodesView =  (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.reserve_nodes_fragment, container, false);


                    appState = ((GlobalData)getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                    setCheckBoxes();
                    return reserveNodesView;
           }

          public void setCheckBoxes(){

            LinearLayout ll =     
(LinearLayout)reserveNodesView.findViewById(R.id.child_scrollView);
             for(int i = 0; i < appState.getOrbitAvailableNodes().size(); i++){
                 String node_name = appState.getOrbitAvailableNodes().get(i).toString();

                 appState.setOrbitCheckBoxes(new CheckBox(reserveNodesView.getContext()));
                 appState.setOrbitCheckBoxesText(i, node_name);


                 ll.addView(appState.getOrbitCheckBoxes().get(i));
          }
    }
```

I get the following **error** when i run my application:
 *FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 06:06:39.948: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should call this before ll.addView:

```
Checkbox cb = appState.getOrbitCheckBoxes().get(i):
((ViewGroup)cb.getParent()).removeView(cb);
```

to remove it from it's parent first.

Or just this could work, since you binded to reserveNodesView in constructor:

```
reserveNodesView.removeView(appState.getOrbitCheckBoxes().get(i));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The error still occurs.
Thank you!